# FEM Meshing artifact at nodes with fewer neighbors

Tags: finite-element, mesh

I wrote a 2D-FEM solver to solve some diffusion process and wanted to verify my code with a test problem.
The input was $f(x,y) = x^2+y^2$ and I applied the stiffness matrix on it to get $\Delta f = 4$.
The lumped mass matrix $M$ and stiffness matrix $D$ are assembled from an analytical solution of triangles.

Unfortunately, I get too high values at nodes with fewer neighbor elements (5 instead of six) than average (see below), whereas elements with more neighbors underestimate the analytical value.
I also tried a finer resolution, but this didn't help.

[[image: solution of <span class=]$\Delta f = 4$ for $f(x,y) = x^2+y^2$ " />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsQM4.png)

Note that I manually added the value 4 at the boundary nodes, since the corresponding entries in the stiffness matrix are 0.

Do you have an idea, what the problem might be?
In my test simulations for the diffusion process, I couldn't find this meshing artifact. Only in the test problem.

Comment: Have you tested your code by simply projecting a function onto the finite element space, e.g. solve $u = f$ for given $f$ or, equivalently, solve $Mu=f$ where $M$ is the mass matrix? I think you may have implemented the basis functions wrong.

Comment: These elements are only C0 continuous (assuming that you used the standard Lagrange elements). Since the derivatives across elements are discontinuous, it's not a good idea to check for the derivatives in the way you are doing. Compare the solution field instead of its Laplacian. What is the order of the element used for this test?

Comment: @Abdullah Ali Sivas, yes I did that, but the testing ability is very limited because that way I only know that my mass matrix is correctly typed (it's an analytical solution).

Comment: @Chenna K thanks for your comment! I'm aware of the C0 continuity, but can it explain the big error? I used first order elements. What do you mean by solution field? I initialized my field u and then solved My=Ku, with the solution vector y and the stiffness matrix K.

Comment: This is not how we normally test an FE code. We solve for f at the nodes and then check the solution with an error measure, for example, L2 or H1 norm.
I think the issue might be due to the mesh itself, which creeps into the stiffness matrix. Have you tried the same problem on a structured triangular mesh?
Also, try solving the system My=f instead of My=Ku. In doing so, you will get rid off the discrimination error coming from K.

Comment: *not discrimination but discretisation.
For some reason, autocorrect converted discretisation to discrimination.

Comment: @ChennaK discrimination error confused me indeed. Thanks for clearing it up! I'm not sure how to interpret My=f (M - mass matrix). This should give me the vector f projected in finite element space. But this result is not interpretable is it? Also, how does it help solving the Laplacian of the field?

Comment: I agree that solving My=f does not offer much in terms of your problem. But, it helps in testing your implementation.
Your last comment poses more questions. Could you please clarify your objective? Are you trying the solve the diffusion equation or are you solving for the Laplacian? Why do you need the mass matrix?

Comment: @ChennaK I want to solve a diffusion-like time-dependent problem (Richards equation). [earlier post](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/35201/solve-1d-saturation-equation-using-fem?noredirect=1#comment66887_35201). The mass matrix (it's inverse) is necessary to project the solution vector from FEM space back right?

To solve the Laplace test problem, the mass matrix is therefore also necessary isn't it?
Thanks for your effort to help :)

Comment: I don't see why you need the mass matrix for this problem. The current problem and the problem in the other post are different.
To solve the Laplace equation, we don't need the mass matrix. Try solving the solving the Laplace problem, $-\Delta f = g$, first. You will have Ku=F, where K= $\int \nabla N^{T} \nabla N dV$ and F= $\int \nabla N^{T} g dV$

Comment: @ChennaK your clarification made it clear, thanks a lot! I assume you mean F=∫N^TgdV

Comment: Yes. That's correct! Sorry about the mistake in the expression for F in my comment.

Comment: @murcielagos, I suggested testing the projection to see if your implementation is correct. If you choose a function in the finite element space and project it, you should recover it. That is a good indicator of correctness. If that works you can move onto the next step, actually solving the problem. $f=x^2+y^2$ is not in the space so maybe try $f=x+y$ and solve the diffusion-like problem. If you can recover that exactly too, everything is good. But these tests will probably help you figure out what is wrong.

Comment: Check if there is an element size dependence. If you make a few elements bigger, and notice artifacts there as well, it could be a typo in your expression of the stiffness matrix.